# Save the localStorage data in array of objects in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm learning how to use ReactJs.
My problem is that I cannot save the data which is in localStorage in the "data" array in the Component State. Can someone help me. I leave the code below

```
async sendGetRequest(){
    await axios.get('https://nba-players.herokuapp.com/players-stats', this.state)
    .then( res => {
        localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(res.data));
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

    
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.sendGetRequest();
    let result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dati'));
    let playerList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        playerList[i] = {nome: result[i].name, team: result[i].team_name}
    }
    console.log(playerList)
}
```

Comment: You save into local storage as `'data'` but read as `'dati'`.

Answer (score 0):

`sendGetRequest` is promise, isn't solved immediately so, you can pass a callback function after to receive the data

```
    async sendGetRequest(cbk){
        const {data} = await axios.get('https://nba-players.herokuapp.com/players-stats', this.state);
        cbk(data)
    }

    
    componentDidMount(){
        this.sendGetRequest((data)=> {
             //if you want to save the data
             localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
             let playerList = [...data];
             for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                 playerList[i] = {nome: result[i].name, team: 
                 result[i].team_name}
             }
             console.log(playerList)
        });
    }
```

**Tip: don't mix async/await with then**

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like so.

```
async sendGetRequest(){
  res = await axios.get('https://nba-players.herokuapp.com/players-stats', this.state)
  localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(res.data));
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.sendGetRequest().then(() => { 
     let result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
     let playerList = [];
     for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       playerList[i] = {nome: result[i].name, team: result[i].team_name}
     }
     console.log(playerList)
  }).catch((err) => console.log(err));

 }
```

Comment: How can I copy playerList into this.state? How can I use this.setState?

Comment: You can use this.setState after or before ``console.log(playerList)